# Can the functionality of an Orchestrator Function depend on an activity function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have an activity function that pulls data from an api and stores it in a database. the activity function takes a start date as input and collects the data from then until a constant number of days after and returns the last day it collected data on. The activity function cant collect data from start date until the current date as it causes a timeout. The orchestrator function has a while loop that runs the activity function repeatedly until the return date is the the current date.

Is this OK? (is this not deterministic?)

i'm currently getting weird input/output values for the activity function and wondering whether it has to do with the orchestrator depending on the output of the activity function or whether it is another issue.